# Label text wont update C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm new in c# and don't know like anything. It's a program for proxy checking. I want to create a UI for it but the problem I'm having is that I can't pass like Good Results, Bad Results etc from the Program.cs to Form1.cs

My program UI is like this.

```
Good: 0
Bad: 0 
Retries: 0
```

I'm trying to sum "Good", with + 1 every time a "Good" proxy its found. I don't know how to do that, I completed the program I just need to show the results on the UI.
I tried following but the labels text wont update.

Things I tried

Form1.Cs. I wrote this public functions :

```
public void Good1()
    {
        good.Text = (Int32.Parse(good.Text) + 1).ToString();
        good.Refresh();

    }
```

And I called the function in the Program.cs as following

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();    
if(proxy == "live"){
// Some code here.
form1.Good1();
// Some other code here
}
```

I tried

```
good.Update();
```

But when I run the program it wont update the label text on the UI. It stays "0" as I wrote it. I'm not good with C#, this is my first program with C# so I'm desperate.

Comment: Is ur checking proxy method running on a thread ?

Comment: Have you stepped through `Good1()` in the debugger to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
good.Invalidate()
```

Or

```
form1.Invalidate()
```

My C# days are distant, but invalidating as far as I remember should force an update!

Comment: Use a timer for the updating. I use timers to update the labels. On my CPU, RAM, Disk monitor program timers are your best friend in updating labels.